# Аngular обновление модели

Tags: angularjs

Есть таблица, данные которой тянутся с сервера.

В каждой строчке этой таблице есть кнопка на удаление этой строчки(одной записи в таблице, точнее не удалении, а обновлении)
Так вот когда я нажимаю кнопку удалить, уходит запрос на сервер, который обновляет поле.

Как потом обновить view
Пример данных

```
[
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'csdacdcdc'
    },

    {
        id: 12,
        name: 'dvSDSvbf'
    }
]
```

то есть после обновление теперь нужно выводить все данные кроме объекта с id: 11.
Хотел узнать в ангуляре есть какой то готовый способ, или делать вручную
Данные в таблице вывожу через ng-repeat

Разметка

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-tours">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Город</th>
            <th>Тип</th>
            <th>Дата начала</th>
            <th>Количество дней</th>
            <th>Опубликовано</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tour in tours | filter: query">
            <td ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
            <td><a ng-bind="tour.name" href="admin/tour/edit/{{tour.id}}"></a></td>    
            <td ng-bind="tour.town.name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="tour.tours_type.name"></td>
            <td ng-bind="tour.date_start | date">Trident</td>
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                <switcher class="styled"
                          ng-model="tour.published"
                          ng-disabled="isDisabled"
                          ng-change="onChangePublish(newValue, oldValue, tour.id)"
                          true-label=""
                          false-label="">
                </switcher>
            </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTour(tour.id)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Контроллер

```
$scope.removeTour = function(tour_id){
    $http({
        url: "/tour/update-tour",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: tour_id,
            removed: 1
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.init();
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });
}
```

Comment: добавьте [mcve] кода который у вас есть

Comment: да дело не в коде, а в подходе, сообственно вопрос в том, что логичнее, правильнее - идти за данными на сервер или обновлять уже имеющуюся модель в ангуляре

Comment: это два не связанных между собой действия: если надо обновить на сервере - надо идти на сервер, если надо обновить view - надо обновить модель для этого view

Comment: на сервер уже не нужно идти, надо обновить именно view

Comment: в комментарии выше: _если надо обновить view - надо обновить модель для этого view_

Comment: если не знаете как обновить, приведите пример вашего кода, чтобы можно было подсказать для конкретного случая

Comment: собсвенно вопрос как обновить view(удалить из модели запись с определенным id), c учетом того что данные на сервере уже обновились

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39788/discussion-between-grundy-and-ruslik).

Comment: данные просто масив объектов

Answer (score 1):

Для обновления view нужно изменить модель, в данном случае массив tours. Сделать это можно с помощью метода [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), но для этого нужно знать *индекс* удаляемого элемента в массиве. Если бы не использовалась фильтрация

```
ng-repeat="tour in tours | filter: query"
```

можно было в метод `removeTour` передавать сразу индекс

```
ng-click="removeTour($index)"
```

и внутри по нему удалять нужный объект, но так как фильтрация используется индексы в отфильтрованном массиве не будут соответствовать индексам в исходном.

Таким образом нужно определить этот индекс, например, передав сам объект и использовав метод [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tours = [{
        id: 11,
        name: 'csdacdcdc'
      },

      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'dvSDSvbf'
      }, {
        id: 13,
        name: 'asdadasd'
      },

      {
        id: 14,
        name: 'zxczxczxc'
      }
    ];

    $scope.remove = function(item) {
      var index = $scope.tours.indexOf(item);
      $scope.tours.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query" />
  <div ng-repeat="t in tours|filter:query">
    <pre>{{t | json}}</pre>
    {{$index}}
    <input type="button" ng-click="remove(t)" value="remove" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Вторым вариантом может быть использование метода [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), либо [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), для убирания ненужного элемента, например

```
$scope.tours = $scope.tours.filter(function(el){ return el.id != tour_id; })

$scope.tours = $filter('filter')($scope.tours, function(tour) {
    return tour.id != tour_id;
});
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.tours = [{
        id: 11,
        name: 'csdacdcdc'
      },

      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'dvSDSvbf'
      }, {
        id: 13,
        name: 'asdadasd'
      },

      {
        id: 14,
        name: 'zxczxczxc'
      }
    ];

    $scope.remove = function(tour_id) {
      $scope.tours = $filter('filter')($scope.tours, function(tour) {
        return tour.id != tour_id;
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query" />
  <div ng-repeat="t in tours|filter:query">
    <pre>{{t | json}}</pre>
    {{$index}}
    <input type="button" ng-click="remove(t.id)" value="remove" />
  </div>
</div>
```